# adding one more source system on existing installation of content collector

Tags: ibm-content-collector

I wish to add one more source system **Microsoft Exchange** on IBM Content collector server.
I already installed and configured File System on windows server.

So my query is , can I add Microsoft Exchange on existing installation without disturbing **file system**? if yes how can I add ?

Thanks ,
Dattatrey